# Persistent bottom sheet

Tags: android, fragment, frame, fullscreen, bottom-sheet

I have Persistent bottom sheet that include frame. I want to make full screen bottom sheet but I can't.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_fragment1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="open F1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_fragment2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="open F2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/modal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="modal" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {


BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
Button openF1, openF2, modal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    openF1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_fragment1);
    openF2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_fragment2);
    modal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.modal);
    View nested = findViewById(R.id.nested);

    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(nested);

    openF1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setFragment(0);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
    openF2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setFragment(1);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });

    modal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
            bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
        }
    });
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

            String state = "N/A";
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                    state = "collapsing";
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    state = "draging";
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                    state = "setting";
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    state = "expanding";
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    state = "hidden";
                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });


}


public void setFragment(int state) {
    if (state == 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment1);
        ft.commit();
    }else if (state==1){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment2);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

}

**fragment1.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1e1e1e">

<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="frahment1" />
```

**fragment2.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9d4000ff"
tools:context="sarekouche.ir.map2.Fragment2">

<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fragment 2" />
```

When I click to open bottom sheet, bottom sheet is expanded but fragment is not full screen, it is Just as much as `textView` that there is in fragment.